# How message reception order is modeled under Omnet++?

Tags: network-programming, omnet++

I read a lot about messages Sending/Reception under Omnet++, but currently i am asking my self about reception order under Omnet++.

Let say that:

1. I am using a WIFI network card
2. I want to send two messages from A to
   B

**The question  is:** **If i send msg1 then msg2, is it possible that i receive msg2 before msg1 ?**

Based on what i know and what i read, i guess that is not possible, but i will be greatfull if some one can confirm/invalidate it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading properely Omnet++ documentation and by taking into account the evenemential model of the simulator.

It appears that is possible if event related to msg2 reception is scheduled before the one related to msg1